# What does the phrase "lock into" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The context is from the movie "Fear And Loathing In Las Vegas"   One of the characters at the begging of the movie describes the drugs they bought for the trip to Las Vegas.

```
        DUKE:
        We had two bags of grass, seventy-
        five pellets of mescaline, five
        sheets of high powered blotter
        acid, a salt shaker half full of
        cocaine, a whole galaxy of multi-
        colored uppers, downers, screamers,
        laughers... Also a quart of tequila,
        a quart of rum, a case of beer, a
        pint of raw ether and two dozen
        amyls.

        Not that we needed all that for the
        trip, but once you get **locked into**
        a serious drug collection, the
        tendency is to push it as far as
        you can.
```

This is a definition from macmillandictionary I suspect might be the correct one here.

**(lock someone/something into something)** to involve someone or something in a system, plan etc in such a way that they cannot easily escape from it
The currency is now locked into the European Monetary System.
Their strategy is to lock subscribers into long-term contracts.

Does it mean that they got involved in a plan of collecting drugs for their trip to Las Vegas and they felt obliged and compelled to buy as many as they could?

Comment: I don't think ***collection*** here refers to ***picking up, procuring*** the drugs. It's about maintaining a large "stash" of different drugs. A *serious* drug abuser might have a ***drug collection*** the way a philatelist maintains a ***stamp collection***, or an oenophile a ***wine collection***.

Comment: ...in which context, ***pushing it as far as you can*** almost certainly implies ***experimenting with more powerful drugs*** (going out looking to score heroin, after getting "bored" with alcohol and cannabis, for example). See [***gateway drugs***.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gateway%20drug)

Answer (score -2):

You answered your own question.

In this case, "locked in" means that (in your words) "they got involved in a plan of collecting drugs for their trip to Las Vegas and they felt obliged and compelled to buy as many as they could."

Comment: I still don't understand. Instead of downvoting my answer, why doesn't someone post a better answer?